# How can bcp write simple query results to disk faster than SSMS can run the same query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, bcp

Running the following command took `10.922` seconds:

```
bcp "select * from PRMTAJ_Reporting..PINVDET 
     where pnd_date between 77500 and 77600" queryout Test.dat -S . -T -n
```

However, running the same exact select query in SSMS took `28` seconds.  Also, I ran the query in SSMS after the bcp command so it's not like bcp could have benefitted from me having running the query in SSMS first... if anything it would have been the other way around.

I did this for several ranges of pnd_date values and every time was the same.  I ran the bcp command first and then ran the same select query in SSMS and each time the SSMS query took at least twice as long to complete.

SSMS is only retrieving the results whereas bcp has the added overhead of having to write the results to a new file on disk.  This makes absolutely zero sense to me... but I'm hoping I can learn something that will make my SSMS queries as fast as bcp here.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: Have you recalculated statistics and examined the query plan from SSMS?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Indexes were rebuilt prior to running... my understanding is that this updates stats too.  Query plan shows a clustered index scan... there's an index on pnd_date but as I understand it using bookmark lookups on a non-clustered index over this many records is not efficient.  Just for fun I tried making pnd_date the clustered index to see how it would perform and it performed more like the bcp command did.  Of course, it's not the clustered index in production so that doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

bcp is an utility optimized for import export while SSMS is an general purpose utility. It is expected that bcp faster. If it is not faster than SSMS why use it, or why Microsoft provides this utility.

I can generally summarize following points about why bcp is faster.

- SSMS uses .NET therefore it has some overhead compared to bcp
- SSMS has GUI therefore GUI threads consume resources
- Writing file is almost always faster than data binding a grid in .NET which SSMS uses. Actually writing file is very fast operation.
- SSMS most probably uses .NET DataSet/DataTable construct which is an xml with all of its overheads.
- An utility provided for single purpose (bcp import/export) is generally faster than general purpose tool SSMS.

Comment: 1) What does bcp use then that's so much faster than .NET? 2) Try opening a dozen apps and see how much the extra GUI threads affect your query performance.  I doubt it will as long as you're not low on memory. 3) I've benchmarked databinding speed in my apps before.  It's not significant... definitely nothing compared to the 17 second difference we're talking about here. 4) Pretty sure it uses SqlDataReader.

Comment: 5) A single purpose utility isn't faster simply by virtue of the fact that it's single purpose. I'm curious to know why it's faster, and whether I can learn how to improve my code based on that knowledge.

Comment: +1 for the thoughts.  My experience leads me to think these are not the reasons (except maybe for your 1st point... could be that bcp accesses the database in a manner not available to the general population), but I definitely appreciate the effort.

Comment: Just for reference, my query returns about a half a million records.  Doing a "select top 500000 * from pinvdet" finishes in 7 seconds.